# software for mac that can help in design phase (UML?)

Tags: xcode, pseudocode, prototyping

I am looking for a tool/software that can help me in designing my app.

Basically i do not need something like a code generator, but a nice software that let me create blocks where i implement actions (like a class, but just with the declaration of the methods and datatypes/returned types; no implementation) and then let me create relations, like you would have in various classes that interact with each other.

EXample: i make a block and call it "car"; i implement the methods accelerate, break and others; then i create a block called "person"; that interact with the car block.
When I decide to add another class, i simply add another block, and if i try to use this block with the car or the person block, without using the correct datatypes, it will give me an error (like i create a block called elephant, and try to use it on the car).

I've looked at UML, but is mainly on PC, and i need an app for mac; and the majority of the response that i get are oriented to drawing tools like omnigraffle...the problem is that these software are just helping you drawing the classes; and if i gotta make all the work by myself, at this point i use the old pen and paper :D

It would be nice if there is also an exporter to make pseudo code, so i can import it in Xcode and have all the relations implemented, build and see if i get any error; and then start to implement each single method.

Am i dreaming or something like this exist? Visio is cool (when it works); but is oriented for MS platform, not OBJ-C :(

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Jude](http://jude.change-vision.com/jude-web/index.html) is just what you want. It is a tool designed specifically to draw UML diagrams (including the class diagram, that you mentioned in your question).

Since it is a Java application, you can use it in your Mac without problems.

Comment: Thanks!

Downloaded the free version and now i am taking a look at it, trying to understand how it works, but from a first look seems to be the one that would resolve many of my problems :)

BTW the company name changed it to Astah; and even if is for PC it can be used on Mac, as you stated, since it is a java app.

Now i gotta find out if it supports OBJ-C for the code output (that would be awesome!)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Paradigm runs on a number of OSes including OS X and it's fantastic:

http://www.visual-paradigm.com/solution/freeumltool

Granted to get the full feature set you need to buy it, but it can roundtrip 10 languages.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; tried to use it but the free version still require a license...sent the email to request a license about an hour ago and i didn't got a reply yet, so i cannot start it or check it.

Will compare it with Astah and see which one will be better for my needs (i need something really simple, just draw classes, add datatypes and methods and produce pseudocode and i am a happy camper :D)